# Using Action Plans template in your project

Tags: appexchange

I'm still new to SF and trying to understand bit & pieces and my question is why would you use action plans template in your SF project and what is benefit of it?

Any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make sure you understand, action plans functionality is an app in appexchange that can be installed into Salesforce which will expand the standard functionality and it's not part of the vanilla flavour in Salesforce. As it's free and it's an unmanaged package, improving the app, bugs and managing will be done by you as I believe there is no support provided.

One use case for the action plans and the action plan template in general. Say we have a manager and a customer advisor. You have an account in the system which is a client of yours. Upon registration as a client you might have a process, some steps that the customer advisor has to take upon registration.

The action plan template is made up of 3 activities:

1. Send welcome email;
2. Send leaflet with prices;
3. Follow up meeting;

That template can be applied to the account you desire and on the account 3 open activities will be shown, either tasks or events that will be assigned to the custom advisor to complete.

Now imagine you have 10 accounts every day joining up, the manager will apply the template on selected account which then will create 3 open activities which will be completed by the customer advisor. The opposite of that will be the manager having to go through each account and add 3 open activities.

You can apply action plans template on various other objects like Contact, Cases, Opportunities etc.

This is part of a few of other use cases, but I hope you get the feeling of it. Like I said previously you can expand the functionality a little bit more, for example: On a template you have an assigned to field and depending on that the activities will go to that person in particular. Now you could make it a little bit more dynamic and say I want the activities to go to the owner of the account because they know how to deal with the client so on and so forth.

[Action Plans user manual](http://sforce.co/1KtQ7jP)

[Extend Action Plans functionality to custom object user manual](http://sforce.co/1GKb3UH)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but still its getting hard to swallow so based on what you have said the action plans template applies only to the standard object and not to the custom objects? is that possible for you to walk me a very simple example with action plan template please?

Comment: Out of the box action plans only apply to some standard objects, but the good thing is that you can extend it and apply to other standard objects, including your own custom objects. Here is the link for the manual on how to add action plans for custom objects: http://sforce.co/1GKb3UH In terms of example another user manual might help you and show the usage of action plan templates. You can find it at this link: http://sforce.co/1KtQ7jP